# Deviceready function does not fire in cordova 2.8.0 and cordova 2.7.0 while remote loading

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have been trying to call the files from the server side for phonegap for ios.But deviceready function does not fire in cordova 2.8.0 and cordova 2.7.0 while remote loading.

Comment: Some code will be helpful

Comment: I used the same code generated while creating an app.Just the pointed the js location to the local server location .              <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://localhost:8888/www/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"src="http://local/www/js/index.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

If you run it on device, paths of your js are wrong.
Use relative paths, I read that absolute paths are difficult to get with iOS.
So something like this (just a sample) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"src="../js/index.js"></script>
```

Anyway, if you want more help, please give us more details of your issue (description, error message, code, ...)

By the way, have you any error message ?

Comment: I have uploaded www folder fully in the server side,within the index.html which i have uploaded,i have pointed the cordova js to the server location.There is no www contents in the project.